# How to add a custom event tracking with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

Google Analytics custom event not working, as it is not tracked on Google Analytics statistic View. I written code for onclick, but it is not tracked. Here is my code:

```
    <script>
 var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-42651041-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
   })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

   ga('create', 'UA-42651041-1', '1800accountant.com');
   ga('send', 'pageview', '/Step1');
   </script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   function test(){


_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Popup','Click','Step1']);
alert("GA Code executed");
    }
    </script>

    <p onClick="return test()" style="cursor:pointer;">Click Here</p>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is because you are using the old syntax `gaq.push`, which is for the Classic Analytics. You have actually implemented the newer version of GA called Universal Analytics, which uses a different syntax for sending events.

The correct code to use, according to the [Google Developer information](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events), it should be written like this:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', 'label', value);
```

So, using your example, I'd write it something like this:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Popup', 'Click','Step1');
```

**Event**, **category** and **action** are mandatory, while label and value are optional.

Comment: The link appears to be dead

Comment: Appears to be working for me when I clicked it just now.

Comment: Still dead for me, but it works on incognito window somehow